# tensorflow how to group ops from different name scope?

Tags: tensorflow

For example:

```py
for s in xrange(2):

   with tf.name_scope('myscope_%d % s) as scope:

      some ops

      result = a op
```

Then I want to group `myscope_0/result`, `myscope_1/result` together, something like:

```py
allops = tf.group(myscope_0/result, myscope_1/result)
```

How to do it ?  the line above is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
graph = tf.get_default_graph()

var = tf.Variable(0)

for s in xrange(2):
    with tf.name_scope('myscope_%d' % s):
        op = var.assign_add(s + 1)

all_operations = [graph.get_operation_by_name('myscope_%d/AssignAdd' % s) for s in range(2)]
all_op = tf.group(*all_operations)
```

Here I group together update ops for the variable `var` (the first will increment it by `1`, the second by `2`).

---

You can test it:

```py
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print sess.run(var)  # prints 0
sess.run(all_op)
print sess.run(var)  # prints 3
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But if there are more than one AssignAdd op in the graph, it will get the first op, not the last.